# React: Is there a way to append the same instance of a component to two separate child components?

Tags: reactjs, instance

I have a React component named `<Visualizer>` that has a bunch of WebGL elements built into it. 3D animations, geometries, textures, renderer, canvas, WebGL context, etc.

My project has several pages in it. Upon landing, the structure would be something like this:

```
<LandingPage>
  <...>
    <Header>
        <Visualizer />
    </Header>
  <...>
</LandingPage>
```

As you can see, it's nested a few layers down, and each component is its own file.

When the user navigates to the options page, the *same instance* of `<Visualizer>` needs to be appended to a different child component, so the structure would be:

```
<OptionsPage>
  <...>
    <Main>
        {/*Must be same instance, not a new one*/}
        <Visualizer />
    </Main>
  <...>
</OptionsPage>
```

The reason it needs to be the same instance is that the animation need to pick up exactly where they left off on the landing page, and re-initiating all the 3D geometries, textures, and materials in a new `<canvas>` context is very inefficient.

I've tried [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), but they only work with a DOM `HTMLElement`, not with a React component. Is there a way to append the same instance of my `<visualizer>` into multiple children components?

---

#### Update:

I've tried to import a "pre-rendered" component, but it still initiates a new instance each time:

**visualizer.js**

```
class Visualizer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props);
        console.log("New instance");
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <canvas />
        );
    }
}

// "Pre-render" component
const viz = <Visualizer />;

// export pre-rendered version
export default viz;
```

**header.js**

```
// Import
import viz from './visualizer.js';

class Header extends React.Component {
    // Should be using the same intance rendered above
    // ...but instead it initiates a new one
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {viz}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But my console shows that `<Visualizer>` is being initiated from scratch each time a page changes:

```
 New instance
 New instance
 New instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize a variable with the common component like:

```
const visualizer = <Visualizer />
```

and then use it in your pages as:

```
<LandingPage>
    <Header>
        {visualizer}
    </Header>
</LandingPage>

<OptionsPage>
    <Main>
        {visualizer}
    </Main>
</OptionsPage>
```

To export the instance and import it in other files you should do:

Export ('visualizer.js'):

```
const visualizer = <Visualizer />;
export default visualizer;
```

Import in the needed files:

import visualizer from 'visualizer.js`;

Comment: It's not that simple, because each component is nested deep in its own file, and they're invoked with `next-routes` upon navigation.

Comment: can you create this component in it's own file and export it? that way you can import it in the files that you need it.

Comment: I've tried `import Visualizer` then `render(){return (/*...*/<Visualizer />/*...*/)};` in the child components, but as expected, this renders a new instance of the visualizer, instead of appending the existing one.

Comment: every time you write `<Visualizer />` of course renders a new instance of the `Visualizer` class. That's why I wrote `{ visualizer }`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @spaniard but it did not work. The `constructor()` in my `<Visualizer>` still gets called each time a page renders with `{visualizer}` in it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @Marquizzo, I thought it would work. My next suggestions would be that you save `visualizer` state outside the component, and use it to initialize it when need it. You can do this with `redux` if you have other state that you want to save like this, or use a callback and a global variable.